Log4j2 RoutingAppender with ListAppenders across Multiple Threads
(This is a follow-up from my original question: Log4j2 Custom Appender in Maven Surefire: Possible to Reuse Across Threads?)
I'm attempting to unit test the output of any logging coming from Log4j2 in my application Spring application via JUnit5. To help with this, I've created a JUnit5 extension that creates a WriterAppender before each test that I can use to verify any logged messages.
Maven is being used along with the Surefire plugin. By default, Surefire forks multiple threads to speed up testing. However, it's been pointed out that each of these test appenders will also contain the output of other tests that run at the same time.
(I've verified this to be the case for myself.)
It's been suggested to use a RoutingAppender that creates ListAppenders based on the value stored in ThreadContext which I'm attempting to do.
I've reviewed multiple posts, threads and articles about creating such a setup. It looks to be as though the best way to do it is via an XML configuration, and not to do so programmatically as I'm not sure it fits in conceptually with what's being attempted.
I've tried the following XML configuration (and variations thereof):
log4j2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" name="RoutingForTests">
    <Appenders>
        <Routing name="Routing">
            <Routes pattern="$${ctx:appenderName}">
                <Route>
                    <List name="$${ctx:appenderName}" />
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </Routing>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Routing" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>

The ThreadContext is setup (correctly or incorrectly) via a JUnit5 registered extension, e.g.
LoggerExtension.java
public class LoggerExtension implements BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback {
    // ...

    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context) {
        // ...
        ThreadContext.put("appenderName", context.getUniqueId()); // I've even tried hardcoding this value
        // ...
    }

    public void verifyMessage(String message) {
        ListAppender appender = ListAppender.getListAppender(ThreadContext.get("appenderName")); // appender ends up null
        // ...
    }
}

I've also tried using a hardcoded ListAppender name, and tried using the same lookup variable but with a single $ instead of two (but I think that would resolve to a blank/null value since I don't think the ThreadContext has been properly setup at that point, though I can't be sure). I've also tried setting the key for the Route, but to no avail.
I even tried using ThreadId from event but any attempts to lookup the ListAppender have failed as well.
I'm guessing that I'm either missing something or misunderstanding how this is to be applied.
I also tried doing this programmatically but it turned out something of a mess.
Any help would be appreciated, and I apologize ahead of time if it's something simple that I've somehow managed to overlook.
Thank you in advance!
Sources:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#separate_log_files
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender
Log4j2: How to write logs to separate files for each user?
https://lists.apache.org/thread/3n9xqc132pm49w3m67zm6wnjfw6yphkq
Log4J2 with Routing Appenders and ThreadContext


Why are you unit testing logs?

Logs are an important part of any system, be they business-oriented messages or support-/performance-oriented messages. Just like any other subsystem, it's important to make sure that they're working properly when deployed. The last thing I (or anyone else) need is to go troubleshoot an issue or otherwise provide answers that can be furnished by logs, only to have them not in place. Better safe than sorry.

I have used Spring's OutputCaptureExtension and works great. Why it does not work for you?

Because I don’t want to have to change the signature of every unit test I want to check, and because that captures all output. I want to isolate the logs themselves and be extra sure it’s coming from Log4j itself. OutputCaptureExtension is my last resort.

The routing appender is a little bit peculiar, when it comes to property substitution:

The pattern attributes of the Routes element is evaluated twice (at configuration time and each time an event is logged) and therefore requires escaping the $ as you did,
The contents of the Route element, however, are evaluated only once, whenever pattern evaluates to a new value. Therefore it does not require escaping the $.

You should use:
        <Routing name="Routing">
            <Routes pattern="$${ctx:appenderName}">
                <Route>
                    <List name="${ctx:appenderName}" />
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </Routing>

To retrieve the appender specific to a test use:
LoggerContext context = LoggerContext.getContext(false);
RoutingAppender routing = context.getConfiguration().getAppender("Routing");
AppenderControl appenderRef = routing.getAppenders().get(extensionContext.getUniqueId());
ListAppender list = (ListAppender) appenderRef.getAppender();

Note: the list appenders are created lazily, if no message was logged, no appender will be present.
Edit: The behavior of property substitution in the Route element is documented in the Runtime Property Substitution and Route section of the revised manual.

I tried the single $ for the List appender name and it didn’t work, so I’m guessing it’s an issue w how I’m trying to retrieve the List appender.
I’m away from my computer for the day but I’ll try it tomorrow and report back then.
Thank you again for your help!

The routing appender does not register its sub-appenders in the main appender container, so ListAppender.getListAppender does not work. You can only retrieve them by calling RoutingAppender.getAppenders().

I updated the XML and I had to change the last line to ListAppender listAppender = (ListAppender) routingAppender.getAppenders().get(ThreadContext.get("appenderName")).getAppender(); but I get an error saying that get(...) is returning null. I checked the map returned by getAppenders() and it's empty. Is there anything else I can check? I'm clearly doing something wrong but I'm unsure of what.

I corrected the code in the answer according to your comment and it should work. Note that appenderRef will be null if no message was logged, so you might want to add an assertion on that.

I have verified that the message is being logged by asserting to the console immediately after the call to log.info in the class under test. It's still showing that list.getMessages() is empty. I've also confirmed that the ListAppender itself is properly being returned as checking the name of it shows the correct name.
Would it be ok if I reached out to you via DM on here to share more setup details? I respect that you're likely very busy so I understand if it isn't possible.
Thanks either way!

ListAppender can work in two ways: if you provide a layout in your configuration (e.g. <PatternLayout pattern="%m"/>, then ListAppender.getMessages() will be non-empty, otherwise ListAppender.getEvents() will be non-empty. Feel free to DM me.

Ahhh that was it! getEvents() contained what I needed. I didn't know about the difference between that and getMessages(). Thank you so much for all your help!
